# MYSQL Group by with the minimum value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

Hi I've been searching for this, and I've found solutions for other sample code, but I can't figure out how to implement for mine.

```
SELECT `gameDBGames`, `game_id`, MIN(`gamePrice`) AS `gamePrice`
FROM `games` 
LEFT JOIN `platforms` ON `gamePlatform` = `platform_id` 
LEFT JOIN `bundles` ON `gameBundle` = `bundle_id` 
LEFT JOIN `currency` ON `bundleCurrency` = `currency_id` 
WHERE `bundleEnd` > CURDATE() AND `bundleType` = "1" AND `gameDBGames` != "0"
GROUP BY `gameDBGames`
```

Here is my actual query. This returns the minimum price, but do not correspond to the `game_id`. How could I do that? I believe is doing a inner join like this:

```
 SELECT `gameDBGames`, `game_id`, MIN(`gamePrice`) AS `gamePrice`
 FROM `games` 
 LEFT JOIN `platforms` ON `gamePlatform` = `platform_id`
 LEFT JOIN `bundles` ON `gameBundle` = `bundle_id`
 INNER JOIN (....)
 LEFT JOIN `currency` ON `bundleCurrency` = `currency_id` 
 WHERE b.`bundleEnd` > CURRDATE() AND b.`bundleType` = "1" AND g.`gameDBGames` != "0"
```

Thank you.

**EDIT**: Sorry I don't know what I was thinking not posting the table structure.

The game_id is the unique id (e.g. same game but with different prices) , and gameDBGames is an ID for a game (e.g. gameDBGames = 1, can have price 40 or 30) that's why I'm grouping by gameDBGames. An the aim is getting a unique gameDBGames with the minimum price.

What I have.

```
+--------------+---------+----+---------+
| table games  |         |    |         |
+--------------+---------+----+---------+
| game_id      | int     | AI | PRIMARY |
| gameDBGames  | int     |    |         |
| gamePrice    | float   |    |         |
| gamePlatform | tinyint |    |         |
| gameBundle   | int     |    |         |
+--------------+---------+----+---------+

+---------+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| game_id | gameDBGames | gamePrice | gamePlatform | gameBundle |
+---------+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+
|       1 |           1 |        20 |            1 |          1 |
|       2 |           2 |        20 |            2 |          1 |
|       3 |           2 |        15 |            2 |          1 |
|       4 |           3 |        17 |            1 |          1 |
|       5 |           3 |        20 |            1 |          1 |
|       6 |           3 |        15 |            1 |          1 |
|       7 |           4 |        16 |            2 |          2 |
|       8 |           5 |        18 |            2 |          2 |
|       9 |           5 |        14 |            2 |          2 |
|      10 |           6 |        15 |            1 |          2 |
+---------+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

What I get.

```
+---------+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| game_id | gameDBGames | gamePrice | gamePlatform | gameBundle |
+---------+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+
|       1 |           1 |        20 |            1 |          1 |
|       2 |           2 |        15 |            2 |          1 |
|       4 |           3 |        15 |            1 |          1 |
|       7 |           4 |        16 |            2 |          2 |
|       8 |           5 |        14 |            2 |          2 |
|      10 |           6 |        15 |            1 |          2 |
+---------+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

As you can see the game_id do not correspond to the gamePrice. It should be like this.

```
+---------+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| game_id | gameDBGames | gamePrice | gamePlatform | gameBundle |
+---------+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+
|       1 |           1 |        20 |            1 |          1 |
|       3 |           2 |        15 |            2 |          1 |
|       6 |           3 |        15 |            1 |          1 |
|       7 |           4 |        16 |            2 |          2 |
|       9 |           5 |        14 |            2 |          2 |
|      10 |           6 |        15 |            1 |          2 |
+---------+-------------+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

Hope you understand now, sorry for not been more explained before. If you need something else please ask. Thank you.

**EDIT 2 (Mark)**
The solution put by Mark gives me this errors.

- There are gameDBGames repeated.
- Some games are non shown.

I've updated the WHERE clause just in case is needed.

Comment: can you show us the table structure? what table does columns: `gameDBGames`, `game_id`, `gamePrice` belong?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to select? All games, with the lowest price for each? The single game that has the lowest price of any game? All gameDBGames (what does that represent?) values with the lowest-priced game for each? Something else?

Comment: Before posting such question, please consider showing a table structure. :)

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the description now.

Comment: It's a lot clearer, but it still isn't clear which table(s) the columns `gameDBGames`, `game_id` and `gamePrice` are on - this will be necessary, as a correlated sub-query will be required to identify which `game_id` has the lowest `gamePrice` for a given `gameDBGames`.

Comment: all the colums shown are in the same table 'games', the other left joins of the other tables are for querying other colums not selected in the example here.

Comment: Note that your `where` clause has effectively turned the left outer join to bundles into an inner join (assuming that bundle_end and bundle_type are on the bundles table). Consequently, any games that don't have at least one bundles record that satisfies both bundles conditions in the where clause will not be returned by any query that includes that where clause - is this why some games are missing from your results?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT g.`gameDBGames`, g.`game_id`, g.`gamePrice`
FROM (SELECT `gameDBGames`, MIN(`gamePrice`) AS `minPrice`
      FROM `games` 
      GROUP BY `gameDBGames`) mn
JOIN `games` g 
  ON mn.`gameDBGames`=g.`gameDBGames` and mn.`minPrice`=g.`gamePrice`
LEFT JOIN `platforms` p ON g.`gamePlatform` = p.`platform_id` 
LEFT JOIN `bundles` b ON g.`gameBundle` = b.`bundle_id` 
LEFT JOIN `currency` c ON b.`bundleCurrency` = c.`currency_id` 
WHERE ....
```

The `GROUP BY` in the main query should not be required, due to the grouping in the subquery - however, more than one `game_id` will be returned for a given `gameDBGames` *if* there is more than one `game_id` with the same minimum price for a given `gameDBGames`.

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work right some results are not shown and some gameDBGames are repeated (maybe because some prices are the same in some cases?). I've updated the main post with the where clause also

Comment: @xtyp: As I stated in my answer, *more than one game_id will be returned for a given gameDBGames if there is more than one game_id with the same minimum price for a given gameDBGames*. You say *"**maybe** because some prices are the same in some cases"* - are the prices the same, or aren't they? **If** there are multiple `game_id`s with the same minimum price, don't you want to see all of them? If not, how do you want to decide which ones to show? With the games that are missing, are all their `gamePrice` values null? Can you add some examples of missing values to your question?